# sorting by date an array of bean having date member

Tags: android, sorting, comparator

i am having a bean class like

```
public class ItemBean{
    String item_id, item_title, image_url, link_url, description, publish_date,
        in_app_date, sub_section_id, type, duration, orig_url, sync;
    public ItemBean() {  ....  }
    ....
    ....
}
```

now in activity, i am getting values of itemBeans and making list;
to use in comparator. You can see my code;

```
public void sortDate() {
    List<ItemBean> listIB = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
    for(int i=0; i<DispLibActivity.itemListVect.size(); i++)
    {
        listIB.add(DispLibActivity.itemListVect.get(i));
    }
    //      Sorting  Call
    Collections.sort(listIB, ItemSimpleListActivity.compareDate);
    itemBeans = new ItemBean[listIB.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<listIB.size(); i++)
    {
        itemBeans[i] = listIB.get(i);
        System.out.println("Date: "+itemBeans[i].publish_date);
    }
}
```

My Comparator

```
public static Comparator<ItemBean> compareDate = new Comparator<ItemBean>() {
    public int compare(ItemBean one, ItemBean other) {
        return one.publish_date.compareTo(other.publish_date);
    }
}
```

But, i am getting sorted collection as following :-
Date: 1-1-2009 08:00:00 CST
Date: 10-1-2011 08:00:00 CST
Date: 10-1-2011 08:00:00 CST
Date: 12-2-2010 08:00:00 CST
Date: 4-1-2009 08:00:00 CST
Date: 4-18-2011 08:00:00 CST
Date: 4-6-2010 08:00:00 CST
Date: 4-6-2010 08:00:00 CST
Date: 9-20-2011 08:00:00 CST
Date: 9-20-2011 08:00:00 CST
Date: 9-20-2011 08:00:00 CST

Which is not proper sorting order.

Can anyone tell me the alternate ways or what is the bug with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare dates and not strings (publish_date). So in method compare() you parse the String date into a Date object (e.g. via SimpleDateFormat) and compare those two dates via Date.compareTo

Comment: Thanks a lot "207",
it works, you also learnt me SimpleDateFormat

Comment: You are welcome. A little advice: You can also implement Comparable<ItemBean> by your ItemBean class. Then you override compareTo() method and then you can call Collections.sort(yourList). So your code is more "clean" because the comparison is not part of your Activity (public static Comperator..)